# two foreign keys, how to map with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in MySQL, where the first one is called users and the second one is called games. The table structure is as follows.

**users**

- id (primary)
- email
- password
- real_name

**games**

- id (Primary)
- user_one_id (foreign)
- user_one_score
- user_two_id (foreign)
- user_two_score

My games table is holding two foreign relations to two users.

My question is how do I make the model relations for this table structure?? - According to [the laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), I should make a function inside the model and bind it with its relations

for instance

```
public function users()
{
    $this->belongsTo('game');
}
```

however I can't seem to find anything in the documentation telling me how to deal with two foreign keys. like in my table structure above.

I hope you can help me along the way here.

Thank you

Comment: Was some of the answers useful? Provide feedback.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A migration:

```
$table->integer('player1')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('player1')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('player2')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('player2')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

And a Model:

```
public function player1()
{
    $this->belongsTo('Game', 'player1');
}
public function player2()
{
    $this->belongsTo('Game', 'player2');
}
```

**EDIT**
changed 'game' to 'Game' as user deczo suggested.

Comment: You just need to use exact model name, which is probably `Game`. Otherwise this will throw `class game not found` fatal error.

Comment: Thank you, as I understand you just make a new 'relationship' function for each relation in the table? I haven't my working computer with me, but I will try it out later :)

Comment: Sure, you can name the filed as you want, if it it not following the naming convention, you must specify the name as a second parameter in relation function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the way you have this setup is not likely to work in the current context.  You may have more luck with the belongsTo method, but again that only supports one relationship.

You could implement a user1() belongsTo, a user2() belongsTo and finally just declare a non eloquent function to return both (something like $users = array($this->user1(), $this->user2())