# Laravel Eloquent Relations: Saving two foreign keys at once

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent, relationship

I have a Resource and a Post model. An resource can be either an image (the address of the image) or a text.
An entry in the posts table is to relate two of the entries on the resources model.[image]

Hence, posts uses two foreign keys, both refer to the resources.id column.
I have found [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061687/two-foreign-keys-how-to-map-with-laravel-eloquent) but it doesn't say anything how to presist the attribute without getting a foreign key integrity constraint violation.

These are what I have tried so far to no avail:

```
        //$post->resources($image);//Doesn't add image_id
        //$post->resources($text);//or text_id, doesn't work, no type-hinting

        //$image->post()->associate($post);//tries to save into resources
        //$text->post()->associate($post);//and not post

        //$post->resources()->push($image);// push is just like save
        //$post->resources()->push($text);// only it will save the updated
        //$post->push($text);// relations as well
```

I already know the problem with the codes/attemps above; they are just FYI.

The frustrating thing is that `$post->image()->save($image)` will try to insert into the resources table and not the posts table. Furthermore, the inverse, `$image->post()->save($image)` is missing the text_id.

I also have tried: `$post->saveMany(['text'=>$text,'image'=>$image]);` and it just doesn't do anything.

If you require anymore details, please leave a comment.
P.S. I don't have enough points to ask anything in the SO's related posts comments, otherwise I wouldn't start a new question.

Comment: Can you show the code defining the relationships on the `Resource` and `Post` models? It sounds like there may be an issue there.