# Laravel relationship, one database has two foreign keys

Tags: database, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

This is my **Location** table:

```
ID
Name
Type
```

This is the **Routes** table:

```
ID
Location_start(int)
Location_distination(int)
Distance
Rate
```

I try to achieve a relation between these two tables, so I could get in a foreach loop the location name of the `location_start` and the `location_distination`. I tried it with:

```
public function locationStart()
{
$this->belongsTo('App\Route', 'location_start');
}
public function locationDistination()
{
$this->belongsTo('App\Route', 'location_distination');
}
```

But it didn't work this way.

Comment: Please a) tell us which, if any, of the columns are foreign keys and what to they reference b) which model did you put this (relationships you posted) in.

Comment: Try using `hasOne` instead of `belongsTo`.

Comment: @devk Location_start and Location_distination.In the Locations Model

Comment: Then just change `->belongsTo('App\Route', 'location_start')` to `->hasMany('App\Route', 'location_start')`. Same for loc_end. You defined the inverse (you would use `belongsTo` in Route model, because the `routes` table has foreign key (thus 'belongs to')).

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25061868/4668162 , make sure your migration or table is constructed correctly

Comment: @Onix What is the inverse of this one ?

Comment: Routes looks like it's a pivot table, you don't need a model for it. Just put `belongsToMany('App\Location',"location_start")` to point to other locations.

Comment: @apokryfos `App\Route::find(20)->locationStart->toArray()`
This is what I get
   `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method 
   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::locationStart()'`

Comment: @MauriceSchilpp I stand by my initial statement that `Route` is a pivot and should not be made into a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route class should look like:

```
class Route extends Model
{
    public function locationStart()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'location_start');
    }

    public function locationDestination()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'location_distination');
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
$route = Route::with('locationStart', 'locationDestination')->find(20);
$route->locationStart->Name;
$route->locationEnd->Name;
```